# Java Applet, works in eclipse, not chrome

Tags: java, html, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I have a very simple java applet, that Im using source code from the docs.oracle(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html) site that should work, and it works in eclipse just fine, it's getting it onto the page that's the problem. The file is on a localhost server at localhost/applet/applet.html and I have the file JavaQuiz.jar in the same directory. My html file is as follows.

```
<hmtl>
<applet codebase="localhost/applet/"
    code = 'JavaQuiz.jar' 
    archive = 'JavaQuiz.jar'
    width = 300
    height = 300 />
</html>
```

Is there something Im missing? Or need to change? I look forward to any help that could be given, and please try to explain it more than telling me the answer so I can learn. :D

This is what is in the java colsole
Java Plug-in 10.5.1.255
Using JRE version 1.7.0_05-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

### User home directory = C:\Users\Jihoon

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

### 0-5: set trace level to

plugin2manager.parentwindowDispose

The Chrome developer help thing doesn't show any problems. And when I click details on the applet it just says classnotfounfexception: JavaQuiz

Comment: 1) Note that an applet element should never be 'self closed', instead use `</applet>` 2) What is the directory structure of the server in relation to the HTML and Jar?  Where are they?

Comment: they are on my localhost server so http://localhost/applet/ then in that folder are teh jar, and applet.html. The jar is made from one java file(JavaQuiz.java) containing a class called JavaQuiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<applet 
    archive="http://localhost/applet/JavaQuiz.jar" 
    code="JavaQuiz.class"
    width = 300
    height = 300 />
</html>
```

I think the biggest problem is not having the `http://` I'm not entirely sure about the other parameters. Play around with that.

So in your case change `codebase="localhost/applet/"` to `codebase="http://localhost/applet/"`

Comment: This is a fragile answer that will not work for the applet at run-time.

Comment: Yes I am aware, I just wanted to point out that `localhost/applet/` was not a full path name as he thought it was.

Comment: *"Yes I am aware, I just wanted to point out that `localhost/applet/` was not a full path name as he thought it was."*  It is a path relative to the directory containing the HTML.  `/localhost/applet/` OTOH would be a path relative to **the root of the site.**

Comment: yes. I understand the difference, wording aside. I'm well aware, that /a/b/ is a path relative to root, and without the front slash it's relative to the current directory, etc, hence me not typing any of those in my answer, but instead making it `http://localhost/applet/JavaQuiz.jar`, A fully qualified url.

Comment: *"A fully qualified url."*  Which is what makes the HTML 'fragile' to being moved to the production server.  Relative references are preferable.

Comment: That's fine. I `completely` agree with you and your answer, I also use relative paths for these scenarios. I just wanted him to understand why HIS code wasn't working. You're response explaining the difference between paths, I also completely understand. And as to your response to my comment on your answer, It was because I thought you're response to me lacked tact.

Comment: *"I just wanted him to understand why HIS code wasn't working."*  (considers) Fair enough.  I often use 'partial answers' to get the OP one step further, and sometimes (OK often) that backfires when the OP accepts the (1st step) answer.  I'll concede that although your answer was not optimal in the long term, it was not intended as a long term answer.  At the very least it will result in more questions from the OP.  ;) Also, +1 for getting them from 'no applet' to 'applet on screen'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. :) I will do my best in the future, to more clearly read the billet points in an answer before commenting, and try to elaborate more on some more optimal solutions.

Comment: *"I will do my best in the future, to.."*  Classic.  And I'll do mine not to allow my slight irritation at a person asking a question, to boil over into 'shouting and waving about of arms' at the person that provides the accepted answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The `code` attribute should point to a fully qualified class name, not to a jar.

Comment: Meaning? It should point to the class name that contatins the init() function in the jar file?

Comment: Yes. the class extending Applet or JApplet.

Comment: Okay so since the class is JAvaQuiz, it should be JavaQuiz.class right?

Comment: No ".class" on the end, but it will need any package name before it.

Comment: and how do I know the package name? I never really messed with those before.

Comment: Do you hava a line at the very top of your JavaQuiz.java file (preceded only by comments) that says "package ..."? What follows the word package is the package name.

Comment: OK should be just "JavaQuiz" then.

Comment: Okay I tried that now, with the new html becoming
<html>
<applet codebase="localhost/applet/"
    code = 'JavaQuiz' 
    archive = 'JavaQuiz.jar'
    width = 300
    height = 300 />
</html>
Still not working, Im still getting a classnotfoundexception

Comment: Right. Edit your question to include, as fully as is reasonable whatever you're getting in the java console. You can also look at the Chrome developer tools (F12) "network" tab, to see if your resources are being found and loaded correctly.

Comment: *"Still not working"* Be sure to flush the class cache between runs.  IT is done using the Java Console.

Answer (score 2):

Also you should have an eye on `localhost...` this means that the j.jar is located in a folder called localhost in the same directory that the html is in. Is that true? Or do you mean `http://localhost:80/applet/` or `/applet/`

Comment: Full file path is http://localhost/applet/ that has both the html file, and the JAvaQuiz.jar whihc contatins a class called JavaQuiz, which extend JApplet, which has the init() function.

Answer (score 1):

`<hmtl>` should be `<html>`

Comment: Good eye, but that didn't fix it. :(

Answer (score 1):

The mandatory "code" attribute (which is missing in your example) should point to the class which you intend to run (the one extending JApplet). Something like:

```
<html>
<applet codebase="localhost/applet/" code="yourpackage.YourApplet.class"
    code = 'JavaQuiz.jar' 
    archive = 'JavaQuiz.jar'
    width = 300
    height = 300 />
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, then I have 2 code attributes, also im still kind of new to java, so what would yourPackage and yourApplet be in this case?
Would package be JavaQuiz and since the class that has init() in it is JavaQuiz, would the Applet also be JavaQuiz resulting in JAvaQuiz.JavaQuiz.class?

Comment: What is the structure of your jar? If you unpack it, in what directory does the JavaQuiz.class file lie?

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost/applet/JavaQuiz.jar` will not work at time of deployment.

```
<html>
<applet 
    codebase="."
    archive="JavaQuiz.jar" 
    code="JavaQuiz"
    width = 300
    height = 300 >
</applet>
</html>
```

Since the code base points to the 'current directory' this will work for the applet while on localhost as well as deployed live.

Points, some of which have already been mentioned:

1. The code attribute should be the fully qualified class name of the applet class, without `.class` on the end.
2. The applet element cannot be 'self closed' - always use `</applet>` to close the element.
3. If omitted the code base defaults to the directory the HTML is in, so putting `codebase="."` is redundant.  It should also work without it.

Comment: "Won't work" is about as useful as a screen-door on a submarine.  What error do you get?

Comment: I get a classnotfoundexception. Also nice expression!

Comment: @kenny **No, but wait, let me reconsi.. *NO!***  That is NOT the problem.

Comment: What are the (copy/pasted) URLs you use to access the applet Jar file, and the applet HTML?  Copy/paste them from the address bar of your browser (but check them first).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Does this really justify Bold and exclamation marks? :P I didn't see Samuraisoulification bold "This one WON'T work either." I'm Just trying to be helpful, should be a bit more respectful.

Comment: @KennyCason  *" Does this really justify Bold and exclamation marks?"* Yes it sure does, since it has already been mentioned in comments & one answer in this question and scores of times on other questions.  I thought maybe if I ***said it a little louder*** you might hear me this time.  If you don't understand something I write, request clarification rather than contradict me with your guess-work.  I consider *that* to be disrespectful.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Well, enjoy the internet. You will make many friends with your pleasantness. In the meantime also enjoy discouraging people to comment/post. Also, It wasn't guess work to me, as I have always added .class, I sure hope you don't go around "TALKING LOUDER" to everyone on SO who says something that isn't correct. OTOH thanks for your contributions to SO as shown by your REP...

Comment: @AndrewThompson And I didn't see you going around flaming the other answers here that were also misleading/wrong. And btw, yelling never solves problems.